# Removing "Continue Reading" from the Excerpt on certain template pages

Tags: wordpress

On the following development site, I have a main Products (custom post type) page:

http://keg.brettatkin.com/products/

I want the "Read More" on this page.

When I click through to a specific product, I'm using the Excerpt as the the basic product description and do not want the "Read More" displayed.

http://keg.brettatkin.com/products/creating-compelling-communication/

I have a custom template for the product description pages.  How do I remove the "Read More" from this template page?

Thanks

Brett

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in your functions.php file of your theme, look for a line that starts with.

```
add_filter('excerpt_more',
```

It will have 2 arguments and look similar to

```
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

the 2nd argument is the function that prints the "read more" so look for the function in this case 'new_excerpt_more' and return ''; after the function declaration.

```
function new_excerpt_more()
{

    if(is_page('excerpts') return "";

    // old code here 

}
```

Comment: I understand this, makes sense.  But how does this allow me to show it on some pages and not others?  Your code look like it removes the "read more" for all excerpts.

Comment: I think you should use different page templates, and run an if statement in them to check the page. And then you add the add_filter in your page, not in functions.php

Comment: Put an if conditional in this function too look for the pages you want this action to happen on

Comment: do you have a code example for excluding certain pages (or template page)?  Thanks

Comment: I added it, the if statement excludes a page called "excerpts"

Comment: I don't think that will do it. [link] http://keg.brettatkin.com/products/creating-compelling-communication/ This page uses the excerpt for the first part and the main post content under the "Detail Description"  I need the "Learn More" to not display on this page.  This is using a version of the single.php page for the custom post type.  I hope this makes sense....